# UIAppearance in Static Library

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, static-libraries, uiappearance

We provide our clients with a static library that allows them to display our viewcontrollers.  We use `UIAppearance` to set the style of our `UIViewController`s.

However, using `UIAppearance` customizes the appearance for those who use the static library as well but we want it to only apply it to our static library.

Is there a way to make `UIAppearance` on the library level?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Think in terms of `[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:..` method. Not sure how you will define the `ContainedIn` part here.

Comment: NICE, this will definitely work...do you know of a way to list all classes in our static library?

Comment: `containedIn` part accepts, something like `[UIPopoverController class]` etc.. So you might have to subclass all UI controllers and provide that here as `[CustomController class]` etc.. Not sure how you will achieve this. Check http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfcm/UIAppearance/appearanceWhenContainedIn:

Comment: perfect answer...not sure how to mark it as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the method as `[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:(Class <UIAppearanceContainer>)ContainerClass,...] setProperty:]`

For example,

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil]
       setTintColor:myNavBarColor]
```

`containedIn` part accepts, something like `[UIPopoverController class]` etc.. So you might have to subclass all UI controllers and provide it as `[CustomController class]` in `appearanceWhenContainedIn` method. For more details on `appearanceWhenContainedIn` method, [check apple documentation here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfcm/UIAppearance/appearanceWhenContainedIn)